# Default value in react select missing in Option component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select library. Bellow i used the [docs](https://react-select.com/components) to create a custom Option component.

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

const CustomOption = ({ innerProps, isDisabled, selectProps }) =>
  !isDisabled ? (
    <div {...innerProps}>{/* your component internals */}</div>
  ) : null;

class Component extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Select defaultValue={my values} components={{ Option: CustomOption }} />;
  }
}
```

How you can see i set defaultValue, but doing console.log(selectProps) in CustomOption component, there is not defaultValue prop. How to make that prop to appear in that component?